# Como Passar Argumentos a uma class Ex: Dim t as new TL("string","string","string")

Tags: vb.net

Estou com um problema que esta virando minha cabeça ao contrario! Estou construindo uma DLL de conexão com servidor **FTP** mas logo de cara me deparo com o seguinte problema:

Preciso declarar a class em um formulário para abrir a conexão com o Servidor **FTP**, mas nesta declaração da class a variável tem que conter o **FTPServ** , **Usuário** e **Senha**. Mas ai está o problema. Eu não consigo criar string para uma class, tenho tempo programando mas em javascript para jogos!

Exemplo:

```
Imports Servidor.FTP

Dim FTPServ As New FTP("Servidor", "Usuário" , "Senha")
```

Mas o visual Studio fala o seguinte

**Too many arguments to "Public Sub New"**

Declarei as Property de Hostname, Usuário E Senha e Usei a Sub New mas nada da certo.

Código Inicial da DLL

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.NetworkCredential
Public Class FTPServ
    Dim URIFTP As String = ""
    Dim SWServidor As WebRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(URIFTP)

    Public _Host As String
    Public _Password As String
    Public _User As String



    Public Property HostnameP As String

        Get
            Return _Host
        End Get
        Set(ByVal V As String)

        End Set
    End Property



    Public Property UsuárioP As String

        Get
            Return _Host
        End Get
        Set(ByVal V As String)

        End Set
    End Property




    Public Property SenhaP As String

        Get
            Return _Password
        End Get
        Set(ByVal V As String)

        End Set
    End Property



    Public Sub New(ByVal usuário As String, ByVal Senha As String, ByVal Domain As String)
        Me._Host = Domain
        Me._Password = Senha
        Me._User = usuário
    End Sub


    Public Function UploadFile(ByVal URLArquivo As String, Destino As String)
        ' SWServidor.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Hostname, Usuário, Senha)
        SWServidor.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
        Try

            Dim ByteFile() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Destino)
            Dim MyStream As System.IO.Stream = SWServidor.GetRequestStream()
            MyStream.Write(ByteFile, 0, ByteFile.Length)
            MyStream.Close()
            MyStream.Dispose()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox("Erro")

        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: A sintaxe está errada. De que tipo de deve ser a variável `FTPServ`? Tem alguma documentação desta classe? Seria bom ver o construtor deste tipo para ver se está batendo com o que você está usando. Sem ver como ela está não tem como responder.

Comment: Parâmetros passados na criação da classe não correspondem com o construtor.

Comment: FTPserv é uma referencia a class FTP e essa classe FTP tem que obter esses parametros de servidor senha e usuário

Comment: Posta aí o código do construtor da classe FTP.

Comment: da uma olhadinha ai já fiz de varias formas mas na hora de declara a variavel no form o VS ainda diz too many arguments

Comment: Boa tarde, conseguiu resolver o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro `Too many arguments to "Public Sub New"` quer dizer que você passou argumentos a mais no método construtor. Olhando o código parece que a quantidade de argumentos está ok:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal usuário As String, ByVal Senha As String, ByVal Domain As String)
    Me._Host = Domain
    Me._Password = Senha
    Me._User = usuário
End Sub
```

Mas então notei que a sua classe se chama `FTPServ` e não `FTP` como dito nas outras resposta, porém mesmo você trocando o erro continuou, então notei que você está importando `Imports Servidor.FTP`, porém em outras linguagens de programação o nome do arquivo tem que ser equivalente ao nome da classe.

Então o correto seria usar isto:

```
Imports Servidor.FTPServ
```

e isto:

```
Dim ftp As New FTPServ("Servidor", "Usuário" , "Senha")
```

É provavel que você tenha criado mais de um arquivo e esteja editando e importando o errado e por isto o erro dos argumentos continuam, pois você editou o arquivo correto mas importou o erro (eu acho, não tenho certeza).

Answer (score 0):

Sua classe não se chama `FTP`, mas FTPServ, fiz umas modificações:

```
Public Class FTPServ
    Dim URIFTP As String = ""
    Dim SWServidor As WebRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(URIFTP)

    Private _Host As String
    Private _Password As String
    Private _User As String

    Public Property HostnameP As String

        Get
            Return _Host
        End Get
        Set(ByVal V As String)

        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property UsuárioP As String

        Get
            Return _Host
        End Get
        Set(ByVal V As String)

        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property SenhaP As String

        Get
            Return _Password
        End Get
        Set(ByVal V As String)

        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal usuario As String, ByVal senha As String, ByVal domain As String)
        Me._Host = domain
        Me._Password = senha
        Me._User = usuario
    End Sub


    Public Sub UploadFile(ByVal URLArquivo As String, Destino As String)
        ' SWServidor.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Hostname, Usuário, Senha)
        SWServidor.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
        Try

            Dim ByteFile() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Destino)
            Dim MyStream As System.IO.Stream = SWServidor.GetRequestStream()
            MyStream.Write(ByteFile, 0, ByteFile.Length)
            MyStream.Close()
            MyStream.Dispose()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox("Erro")

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

    Public Sub New(ByVal usuario As String, ByVal senha As String, ByVal domain As String)
        Me._Host = domain
        Me._Password = senha
        Me._User = usuario
    End Sub


    Public Sub UploadFile(ByVal URLArquivo As String, Destino As String)
        ' SWServidor.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Hostname, Usuário, Senha)
        SWServidor.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
        Try

            Dim ByteFile() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Destino)
            Dim MyStream As System.IO.Stream = SWServidor.GetRequestStream()
            MyStream.Write(ByteFile, 0, ByteFile.Length)
            MyStream.Close()
            MyStream.Dispose()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox("Erro")

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Você declara assim:

```
Dim ftp As New FTPServ("Servidor", "Usuário" , "Senha")
```

Comment: Já tentei assim mas o VS continua dizendo Piblic Sub New() e não reconhece as string

Answer (score 0):

> Dim FTPServ As New FTP("Servidor", "Usuário" , "Senha")

Se realmente está fazendo esta chamada o erro está no **"New FTP"**

Comment: è n entendo muito de vb mas pelo que já vi o VS me lancaria uma exceção de referencia de objeto não definada para uma instância do objeto

Comment: Veja a resposta atualizada do outro colega.